# Apollo-Client - Error: Could not identify object

Tags: reactjs, caching, graphql, apollo-client, postgraphile

Client - React, Apollo-Client, codegen

Server - Postgraphile

The app view list of file objects.

Users can add new file.

I wrote a Query for getting the file objects from the server.

And a Mutation for adding new file.

they both works.

what Im trying to achieve is updating the cached files with the new file, and re-render the component that contain the FilesQuery hook.

I followed this doc: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#the-update-function

but calling `cache.writeFragment` keep throwing the error:

```
Error: Could not identify object {"id":"de5b015b-28a8-4066-a5ed-44dcead659ed","createdAt":"2022-10-14T14:51:14.874548645","updatedAt":"2022-10-14T14:51:14.874550045","originalFileName":"MY_FILE.xlsx",...}
```

**Files Query**

```
query FileUploads(
  $offset: Int = 0
  $first: Int = 10
  $orderBy: [FileUploadsOrderBy!] = [CREATED_AT_DESC]
  $filter: FileUploadFilter
) {
  fileUploads(
    first: $first
    offset: $offset
    orderBy: $orderBy
    filter: $filter
  ) {
    totalCount
    nodes {
      id
      uploaderOrgId
      uploadFileType
      counterPartiesCount
      parsedPointsCount
      effectiveDate
      originalFileName
      configFileName
      createdAt
      status
      partiesIds
      parsedFileUrl
      uploadingOrg {
        id
        shortName
      }
      entitiesAndCps {
        entities {
          id
          shortName
        }
        cps {
          id
          shortName
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Table Compoent (Calls FileUploadsQuery)**

```
const FileUploadsTable = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useFileUploadsQuery();
...
}
```

**Mutation - Update**

```
update(cache, { data }) {
      cache.modify({
        fields: {
          fileUploads(existingFileUploads = {}) {
            const newFileUplodsRefs = (
              data?.uploadToService?.result as any[]
            ).map((file) => {
              return cache.writeFragment({
                data: file,
                fragment: gql`
                  fragment NewFileUpload on FileUpload {
                    id
                    uploaderOrgId
                    uploadFileType
                    counterPartiesCount
                    parsedPointsCount
                    effectiveDate
                    originalFileName
                    configFileName
                    createdAt
                    status
                    uploadingOrg {
                      id
                      shortName
                    }
                    entitiesAndCps {
                      entities {
                        id
                        shortName
                      }
                      cps {
                        id
                        shortName
                      }
                    }
                  }
                `,
              });
            });
            return [
              ...(newFileUplodsRefs as any[]),
              ...(existingFileUploads?.nodes || []),
            ];
          },
        },
      });
    },
```

**EDIT 1**

i managed to pass the error by passing:

```
cache.writeFragment({
                id: `FileUpload:${file.id}`, <--
                data: file,
                fragment: gql`
                  fragment NewFileUpload on FileUpload {
                    id
                  }
                `,
              });
```

also changed the return object to:

```
return {
              nodes: [
                ...newFileUplodsRefs,
                ...(existingFileUploads?.nodes || []),
              ],
            };
```

still i don't see the re-render, in the component that display the `FileUploads`.

(the component is `FileUploadsTable`)

Comment: Please provide the full code, not just small incomplete snippets. If you're sure the error is fixed, maybe you can rephrase the question?

Comment: Hi, did you event managed to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

**apolloClient**

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        shells: {
          keyArgs: (args, context) => {
            const {
              variables: { filter, runFilter } = {},
              fieldName,
            } = context;

            return `${fieldName}${
              isEmpty(filter) && isEmpty(runFilter)
                ? ''
                : ':' + JSON.stringify({ filter, runFilter })
            }`;
          },
          merge(existing = [], incoming, { args, cache, variables }) {
            const { offset = 0 } = args;
            if (Array.isArray(existing)) {
              return incoming;
            }

            const merged = { ...existing, nodes: existing.nodes.slice(0) };
            for (let i = 0; i < incoming.nodes.length; ++i) {
              merged.nodes[offset + i] = incoming.nodes[i];
            }
            return merged;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: `${
      typeof window === 'undefined' ? 'http://localhost:3009' : window.origin
    }/frm/api/graphql`,
  }),
  defaultOptions: {
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
    },
  },
});
```

**Shell Component**

```
  const loadMoreShells = async (page: number) => {
    setIsPageLoading(true);
    await fetchMore({
      variables: {
        first: SHELLS_PER_PAGE,
        offset: SHELLS_PER_PAGE * (page - 1),
        filter: { ...filter, ...{ pinned: { equalTo: false } } },
        runFilter: runFilter ? { run: runFilter } : undefined,
        orderBy: [
          STATUS_ASC,
          SHELL_RUNS_MAX_CREATED_AT_DESC,
          EXECUTION_FROM_DESC,
        ],
      },
    });
  };
```